# Is there a way to gather all fields in a form into a 2D array for writing to Google Sheets?

Tags: multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Goal: I am looking to create a custom form using Google App Scripts to submit data with a varying number of rows to a Google Sheet. Essentially, there will be a few basic fields but then there is a table structure and the user will be able to push a button to add another row to the end of the table. Once they submit the form the results will be appended to a Google sheet.

So far, I've created the form and it allows you to add 2 more divs containing fields. I do not want to manually map each field into an array to send it to Google so I am looking for the cleanest way. 
I tried to pull all form fields at once and considered pulling them by class. I have it where the 2D array would write to the Sheets but I'm having problems getting the data to do so.

```
'''html
<form id="soulTestForm">

<div class="block">
 <div>
 <label for="name1">Name</label>
 <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" placeholder="A Fancy Name">
 </div>

<div>
    <label for="count1">Count</label>    
    <input type="number" name="count1" id="count1" placeholder="100">
</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
 <div>
 <label for="name2">Name</label>
 <input type="text" name="name2" id="name2" placeholder="A Fancy Name">
 </div>

<div>
    <label for="count2">Count</label>    
    <input type="number" name="count2" id="count2" placeholder="100">
</div>
</div>
  <button type="button" name="addSection" id="addSection" value="Add an Entry" onclick="addBlock();" >Add a Section</button>
 <input type="submit" onclick="this.value='Magic ...'; google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(formSubmitted) .writeForm(this.parentNode); return false;">
</form>
<script>
function addBlock() {
  var block = document.getElementsByClassName('soulBlocks');
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < block.length; i++){
    console.log("i=" + i);
    if (block[i].style.display=="none"){
      console.log("block if");
      block[i].style.display="block";
      if (i == block.length-1) {
        document.getElementById("addSection").style.visibility="hidden";
        }
      break;
    }      
  } 
}
</script>


'''Code.gs file
function writeForm(form) {
var fields = [
 [form.name1, form.count1],
 [form.name2, form.count2]
 ]; 
}
```

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of `I'm having problems getting the data to do so`?

Comment: Your "code.gs" assumes existence of `form.name1` and `form.name2`. Could you not preface the array by testing for existence of form.name3 (and 4); if yes, then push name and value onto array, and proceed as before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Flow:

- Get all keys of `form` object as a array  using `Object.keys`
- Split the keys  array into sets of two using `Array.reduce`

#### Snippet:

```js
function writeForm(form) {
  var tempArr,val;
  var arr2d = Object.keys(form).reduce(function(acc,curr,i){
    val = form[curr];
    i % 2 === 0 ? (tempArr= [val]) : (tempArr.push(val), acc.push(tempArr));
    return acc;
  },[]);
  return arr2d;
}
console.log(writeForm({"name1":"Cat","count1":"100","name2":"Mouse","count2":"99"}))
```

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I'm not fully understanding. The 2D array will consist of array's for each line in sheets rather than a key and value.

Comment: @jaime Yes. Isn't that what you want?